# Unusual behavior adding two compound indexes on the same table

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if *compound index* is the right word; what I mean is I have an index that consists of more than one column.

**Problem:**

My primary key consists of two columns and they work fine; columnA and columnB. I run into trouble when I try creating another index on the same table that consists of two columnA and columnC. As soon as I create the 2nd index it takes over and becomes the clustered index so the table gets ordered by it, ignoring the primary key index are created first.

**Possible Solution:**

I want the table ordered by the first index on ColumnA and ColumnB, but I use the 2nd index for other purposes. To solve this problem I could duplicate the data in a 2nd table where ColumnA and ColumnC are the only index but I don't want to do that if it can be avoided.

**System Info:** MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL (and any other SQL engine for that matter), there is NO guarantee that your table is ordered by any particular order. The only way to ensure ordering is to use `ORDER BY` clause.

Now, reason why ordering is not guaranteed if you do not use ORDER BY: as you insert or delete rows, server is free to reuse "holes" for new inserts. Also, server is free to first deliver rows from cache or from where currently disk head is, if that gets better performance - this could be especially helpful if you use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.

So, long story short, simply always use `ORDER BY` in your selects, and your problem will go away.

Comment: I was under the impression that every table has a clustered index and that index is how the rows are physically laid out on disk. When I do a select all on a table the rows returned always reflect that. Isn't ORDER BY used if you want to go against the standard sorting?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil No, that's not true - at least when it comes to MySQL. If `order by` is missing, the db is free to return the rows in whatever order it wants.

Comment: I see. So I'd need to add ORDER BY explicitly for inserts

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil No - you need to add `ORDER BY` when you `SELECT`. You can't control what order the database engine decides to save stuff to disk, and you shouldn't care. You only care about what order you get stuff back in when you select.

Comment: @jcsanyi I see what your saying but I thought the whole purpose of a clustered index was for physical ordering. I do care how it's stored though. Does that not effect how fast it's retrieved if it's not contiguous?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil: granted, clustered index will try to keep physical order as much as possible to improve performance of `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY clustered_index`. But, that physical order is still not 100% guaranteed.

Comment: Hmm. It makes sense. I don't like it but it makes sense.